# evaluated result of indirect function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I'm coding VBA and would like to evaluate whether a particular cell is referring to cells in other sheets or not.  I usually evaluate this by analyzing the characters in the cell's value before "!".

However, this method doesn't work when the cell refers to cells in another sheet using an "indirect" function.

For example, `=INDIRECT (ADDRESS(row, col,,,sheet_name))` or `=INDIRECT ("SUM(" & A1(cell containing sheet_name) &"B2:B3)")` refer to cells in other sheets, but I cannot detect this in VBA because there is no expression like "!" in the formula.

So, could someone help me to find whether there is any method to evaluate indirect functions in VBA, specifically a method to convert `=INDIRECT (ADDRESS(2, 1,,,"sheet2"))` into `=sheet2!A2`, or another way to know whether a cell that contains "indirect" function refers to cells in other sheets or not.

Thank you for your support in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub getRangeAddress()
    Dim oRng As Range
    Set oRng = Evaluate("=INDIRECT(Address(2, 1, , , ""Sheet2""))")
    If oRng.Parent.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        MsgBox oRng.Address(, , , True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Charles,
Thank you so much for your speedy response.

It works very well when indirect function only refers to one cell such as "=INDIRECT(Address(2, 1, , , ""Sheet2""))"
That is alright, but if possible, I would like to detect that even if there are more than 1  cell.

Comment: For instance, when I put "=INDEX(A1:A4, MATCH(INDIRECT(C5&"!B3"),Sheet1!$A$3:$A$7,0))" in cell B4 while cell C5 contains "Sheet2", oRng.Parent.Name is "Sheet1" meaning I cannot detect cell B4 refers to a cell in Sheet2.
So, are there any other way to know all sheets that a particular cell refers to?
Your support is much appreciated

Comment: Not without parsing the formula into expressions and evaluating the expressions individually. There are also a lot of corner cases for things like intersections, multiple range operators etc. See my Beta 4.2 of Formula Explorer Pro. http://www.decisionmodels.com/fxl_mgrpro_beta2.htm

Comment: Thank you, Charles. Your tool works in a fantastic way! I also would like to write a code to see all the precedents in my VBA code, are there any hints (e.g., functions to be used) for me to realize finding all precedents? Your expertise is highly appreciated because there are no other websites that I can refer to...

Comment: Maybe you can parse out the INDIRECT and OFFSET functions, use the Evaluate trick in the code above to convert them to range adresses and substitute back into the formula?